# Is this a good way to think about solar cells?

Tags: resistance, solar-cell, ohms-law, solar-energy

Imagine we want to power a load with resistance R with a Solar Panel.

To figure out how the solar panel will interact with it, draw a line with slope 1/R on an IV graph. Where that line and the solar panel's IV curve intersect is what the voltage and current of the interaction will be.

Comment: This is exactly what SPICE does and why it's such a powerful tool.

Comment: Lucian, before computers and calculators were so prevalent that most of them are now found in land fills, when one used a hand crank on an adding machine to add or multiply, load lines were pretty much what everyone used. And they are useful.

Comment: Lucian, for example, when using the 12AX7 vacuum tube with a \$1.5\:\text{k}\Omega\$ cathode resistor, a \$100\:\text{k}\Omega\$ plate resistor, with a \$250\:\text{V}\$ B+ supply, a page from the datasheet have [this load line (in red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIsTp.png) drawn on it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. And it works for all sorts of things, not just solar cells/panels!

This is a shortcut way to solve simultaneous equations and Kirchhoff's laws in simple cases. When the lines cross, that means you found a current and voltage that can work out for both the solar panel and the load at the same time. It works even if you don't have the equations but only have the graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works and it not only works with solar cells, it works with any circuit element with an IV curve.